# Error al registrar usuariooSQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Permission denied Is the server running on host "10.124.0.2" como solucion

Tags: laravel, postgresql, nginx

Tengo una aplicacion desarrollada en Laravel con un servidor de base de datos en Postgresql. El servidor web y de bases de datos están en diferentes droplets(Digital Ocean). Ambos servidores con Rocki Linux 9.

Al momento de hacer un registro en mi aplicaion de Laravel me da este error:

```
Error al registrar usuariooSQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Permission denied Is the server running on host "10.124.0.2" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? (Connection: pgsql, SQL: insert into "users" ("name", "email", "password", "updated_at", "created_at") values (aaaaaaaaa, aaaaaaa@gmail.com, $2y$12$fuq/aiprDkRxfQtbaoU/Uun2PoWecHBj48t1GzzEcXLz31U1XCqGW, 2024-03-11 01:59:46, 2024-03-11 01:59:46) returning "id")
```

Funciona conectarnos al servidor de Postgresql usando "psql", a través de pgAdmin, puedo insertar en la tabla desde pgAdmin y al momento de realizar las migraciones y seeders se ejecutan perfectamente.

Se ha intentado solucionar con las siguientes operaciones y no se soluciona el error:

- Se configuró la línea: `listen_addresses = '*'` en el archivo `postgresql.conf`
- Se agregó está línea al archivo `pg_hba.con`f: `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`

¿Qué me recomiendan realizar para solucionar este problema?